# MySql SELECT COUNT with two criterias

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm trying to do a query that fetches data per the last hour and the two last hours. It's just a hits counter.

So I would like to get the resultset as follows:

```
id, page_url, last_hour_hits, two_last_hours_hits
```

The table is very simple:

```
id (autonumber)
page_url
time_stamp
```

I tried the query below:

```
SELECT
page_url,
COUNT(page_url) AS last_hour_hits
FROM stats
WHERE time_stamp > '2015-08-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY page_url
```

*('2015-08-01 00:00:00' is calculated for the last hour)*

It works fine, but I have now idea how to add the 'two_last_hours' counter.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your WHERE clause with two hours before ('2015-07-31 23:00:00') and a CASE WHEN to count for the last hour ('2015-08-01 00:00:00') :

```
SELECT 
    page_url,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN time_stamp > '2015-08-01 00:00:00' THEN id ELSE NULL END) as last_hour_hits
    COUNT(*) AS two_last_hours_hits
FROM stats
WHERE time_stamp > '2015-07-31 23:00:00'
GROUP BY page_url;
```

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL you can use the fact that boolean expression returns 1 for true and simplify the query to this:

```
SELECT 
    page_url
    ,sum(time_stamp > (now() - interval 1 hour)) as last_hour_hits
    ,sum(time_stamp > (now() - interval 2 hour)) as two_last_hours_hits
FROM stats
GROUP BY page_url;
```

This uses `now()` to get the current time and subtracts the interval as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much Nir, your solution works fine as well.
I've already used the Pholochtairze answer, but my question is which one is better from the performance point of view. It is an important question because millions of records are suggested in the table.

Comment: Sorry!!! My comment for @jpw.
BTW, I cannot use now() since we track the dates/time on the application server (PHP).

Comment: @YuryN You can substitute `now()` with your datetime literal, it doesn't change the query. See this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/278f6/4

Answer (score 0):

you can use join between two result sets- one for the one hour and the other for the two hours:

```
SELECT stats.page_url, last_hour_hits, last_two_hours_hits from
stats inner join (
SELECT page_url, COUNT(page_url) AS last_hour_hits
FROM stats WHERE time_stamp > '2015-08-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY page_url ) as last_hour 
on stats.page_url = last_hour.page_url
inner join (
SELECT page_url, COUNT(page_url) AS last_two_hours_hits
FROM stats WHERE time_stamp > '2015-07-31 23:00:00'
GROUP BY page_url ) as last_two_hours 
on stats.page_url = last_two_hours.page_url
```